# CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors No Matching Functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I'm using the QR Code creation project at https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator within my project. I've added it in exactly as the instructions say.

I can compile and run the project on my test devices with no problem what-so-ever, but when I try to archive it, I get the following error:

> Path/to/project/Barcode.mm:67:33: No matching function for call to 'CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors'

I am pulling my hair out on this one. Here's the code snippet where it's called along with the variable declarations that it's using.

```
CGImageRef rawImageRef = image.CGImage;

const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
```

Comment: Do you have some build settings configured for debug but not release builds?

Comment: **You win!**

I wasn't building for active architectures only on release, just debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer is in the comments of the question, I'm answering it myself just to have a marked answer. In the build settings for "Build for active architectures only" for Debug I had YES, and release I had NO. I switched the release version to YES, and it worked with no problem.

Thanks to Wain for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 13):

I know the asker found his answer, but my problem was with release build where it is supposed to be NO. Because we want non-active architectures too!

Problem lies in XCode being much more type-strict with 64-bit builds in new XCode 5.1(5B130a). CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors second parameter is CGFloat, so changing the type from float to CGFloat fixed it.

```
//const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};//before
const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};//after

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
```

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I ran into the same problem on another app, had forgotten about this, and actually found my own thread here when googling. That will help a lot!